# Is there a way to test for a player's health Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been trying to make a Dead by Daylight map in Minecraft Bedrock but I can’t figure out how to make it so that when a player gets hit they receive a speed boost.

Answer (score 1):

This can be broken up into 2 problems first we need to detcet if a player hit another player.

First, create two scoreboard objectives: didDamage and hurtTime

```
scoreboard objectives add didDamage stat.damageDealt 
scoreboard objectives add hurtTime dummy
```

Then, run the following commands:

```
scoreboard players add @e hurtTime 1 

scoreboard players set @e hurtTime 0 {HurtTime:0s} 
execute @e[score_hurtTime_min=1,score_hurtTime=1] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a[score_didDamage=1] "Nice hit!" 
scoreboard player set @a didDamage 0
```

Next, do this

```
scoreboard players add @e[type=player] hurtTime 1 
scoreboard players set @e[type=player] hurtTime 0 {HurtTime:0s}
```

Now, we test for the speed boost

```
/testfor @p[scores={hurtTime=..1}]

/effect give @p speed 1 2
```

Hope I got this right. I am still kind of new to!!

Comment: Will I have to put any of the commands into command blocks @circusbaby23

Comment: @DEATHBOI yes :)

Comment: witch commands? @circusbaby23

Comment: @DEATHBOI the last 4 the first 3 are ust setting up the score board

Comment: so i should put /testfor @p[scores={hurtTime=..1}] and scoreboard players add @e[type=player] hurtTime 1 scoreboard players set @e[type=player] hurtTime 0 {HurtTime:0s} in repeting command blocks

Comment: @DEATHBOI you well put scoreboard players add @e[type=player] hurtTime 1 ,
scoreboard players set @e[type=player] hurtTime 0 {HurtTime:0s}/testfor @p[scores={hurtTime=..1}] effect give @p speed 1 2 into commadn blocks

Comment: @DEATHBOI the last 4

Comment: all of them in repeating command blocks? and is there a way to pinpoint who got hit

Comment: @DEATHBOI were it say type=player you can change what the type is and you can also chnage type to equal other things :)

Comment: So i have to put players names in the =player spot @circusbaby23

Comment: will this work for bedrock @circusbaby23

Comment: @DEATHBOI I know it well because i two use beadrock

Comment: do you have a youtube Chanel if you do could you make a tutorial @circusbaby23 or anything like that

Comment: @DEATHBOI that's accally a good idea i well if you wnat me to!!

Comment: if you could it would be so great @circusbaby23